# What would be a single word to mean: repeatedly re-choose one of two options alternately?

Tags: single-word-requests

Words like 'dither' or 'vacillate' both suggest being unable to choose between A or B and never choosing either. Is there a word that means 'chooses A, then goes back on their decision and chooses B, then goes back on their decision again and chooses A and so on'?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Paul

Comment: If I could find it, the word that describes the shift between one [enantiomeric isomer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enantiomer) and the other in chemistry might suit.

Comment: @Kit: I'm no chemist, but are 'enantiomeric isomers' involved in changing the bottle of liquid blue / clear / blue?  http://chemistry.about.com/od/chemistrydemonstrations/ss/bluebottle.htm

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think so.  I'm pretty sure that's an oxidation reaction.  But I'm not a chemist either.

Answer (score 4):

A word choice with little implication of lack of decisiveness is **alternate**:

> The user alternated pressing the buttons A and B.

Comment: This was my first thought also.

Comment: Obviously I'm in a minority here, but *alternate* sounds to me like an odd word to use here. Maybe that's because the derivative word *alternative* closely associates with 'choice', which *is* central to OP's context, whereas *alternate* generally only associates with 'toggle-switching' where choice isn't an option.

Answer (score 3):

If you're a US politician the word is [flip-flop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28politics%29).

Comment: In Australian politics there is the "back flip" but it is not usually repetetive (-:

Answer (score 2):

I think **vacillate** *does* imply actually making a choice, but repeatedly switching to the other position. So I'd use that anyway.

For less formal contexts, **blow hot and cold**, **shilly-shally**, **chop and change** all seem fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

In my house we say "wiffle-waffle" for this. I wouldn't call it standard. But I bet most readers would understand it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that perhaps [tergiversate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tergiversate) would be what you are looking for, with perhaps [prevaricate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prevaricate) and [equivocate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Equivocate) as other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***oscillate*** for that purpose. Think of an oscillating fan, swinging back and forth at a steady pace.

> [os·cil·late](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oscillate)
>   –verb (used without object)
>   1. to swing or move to and fro, as a pendulum does.
>   **2. to vary or vacillate between differing beliefs, opinions,
>   conditions, etc.: He oscillates
>   regularly between elation and
>   despair.**
>   3. Physics . to have, produce, or generate oscillations.
>   4. Mathematics . (of a function, sequence, etc.) to tend to no limit,
>   including infinity: The sequence 0, 1,
>   0, 1, … oscillates.

Comment: This is the perfect word for the alternating part but I can't think of ever hearing it applied to a person - it sounds too mechanical to me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess **fluctuate** is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I propose **waver** and **yo-yo**.

I think that it would be easier to answer this kind of question with an example sentence.